# OkHttp / Retrofit / Gson: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I am having this

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

while trying to retreive data from an API. I am using Retrofit, Gson and OkHttpClient.
I am trying to display data from characters (API: http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/gryffindor) into a RecyclerView.

This is my code, I hope you can find with any clue of what's happening:

```
private void lanzarPeticion(String house) {
    loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .build();

    WebServiceClient client = retrofit.create(WebServiceClient.class);

    Call<Data> call = client.getPersonajes(house);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
            adapter.setPersonajes(response.body().getResults());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG1", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

My WebServiceClient:

```
public interface WebServiceClient {
    @GET("characters/house/{house}")
    Call<Data> getPersonajes(@Path("house") String house);

    @GET()
    Call<Personaje> getPersonaje(@Url String url);
}
```

This is my Data class (for the getResults())

```
public class Data {
    private String count;
    private String next;
    private List<Personaje> results;

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(String next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public List<Personaje> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Personaje> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: See also [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was BEGIN\_ARRAY Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358594/java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-kotli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

As the error clearly says, you are trying to parse JSONArray into a JSONObject

```
@GET("characters/house/{house}")
Call<Data> getPersonajes(@Path("house") String house);
```

This service method expecting JSONObject, but according the logcat shared by in the image, the response is giving JSONArray. Instead you should parse it as:

```
@GET("characters/house/{house}")
Call<List<Personaje>> getPersonajes(@Path("house") String house)
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good reason to use your Data class here (the fact that the class is very generically called "Data" seems to reflect that). You're receiving multiple  `Personaje`, so you should accept multiple `Personaje`:

```
    Call<List<Personaje>> getPersonajes(@Path("house") String house);
```

If you use the Data class, (without List), deserializer will expect a single Object, hence the error (`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT`). You *might* be able to get it to work if you implement List in Data, but it seems like code for nothing when `Call<List<Personaje>> getPersonajes` should work fine.